# C# -> If ... Throw Warning ... Else if... Throw Error.. Else.. Return

Tags: c#, warnings, program-entry-point

Iv'e looked up in a few sites and it seems i have not found an answer
Let's say iv'e got this struct "MyStruct"

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    private int value;
    private MyStruct(int i)
    {
        value = i;
    }
    public static implicit operator MyStruct(int I)
    {
        return new MyStruct(I);
    }
    public static implicit operator int (MyStruct MS)
    {
        return MS.value;
    }
    public static explicit operator uint (MyStruct I)
    {
        return Convert.ToUInt32(I);
    }
}
```

And i want to do on the explicit operator that

```
if (I< 40) Then it will throw a compiler warning
else if (I > 50) Then it will throw a compiler error
else -> it will return a value
```

I know i can use throw exception, but i only want the warning/error part
So it will be like this:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyStruct MS1 = 30;
        MyStruct MS2 = 60;
        Console.WriteLine((uint)MS1);//So it will throw a warning
        Console.WriteLine((uint)MS2);//So it will throw an error
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If i'm trying to do something like that:

```
    public static explicit operator uint (MyStruct I)
    {
        if (I < 40)
        {
             #warning Number must be less than 50 and bigger than 40
        }
        else if (I > 50)
        {
             #error Number must be less than 50 and bigger than 40
        }
        return Convert.ToUInt32(I);
    }
```

It just throws the warning and error without even calling the operator
And i cant use #If/#Else on Variables

And if i will use Obsolete attribute, it will just do the same

Any help will be much appriciate! :)

Comment: You probably can write a [Roslyn extension](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2014/11/14/building-a-visual-studio-extension-with-roslyn.aspx) which generates these errors. You can't do it inside the `if-else` statement.

Comment: That's not possible in C#. I know this is not the answer you expect but..

Comment: What should happen with the following code (warning, error, or none of these): `MyStruct MS1 = new Random.Next(0, 100); Console.WriteLine((uint)MS1);`?

Comment: Note : `I` is not a Good name  for any variable/object, its not readable and cause lots of trouble in big projects.

Answer (score 0):

Even using a Roslyn extension, you would not *in general* be able to achieve this.

In the examples you show, it is in theory possible to do (in Roslyn, which gives you compile-time hooks), but even there would require some non-trivial analysis of the code to identify the values of the `MyStruct` variables as they will be at run-time when the `explicit uint` operator is called.

But any other examples simply would not be able to accomplish this. The `MyStruct` value could come from anywhere, initialized with any value. There's no reason that initialization should occur from an `int` literal that is in the same method being analyzed, and thus the initialization would be hidden from any analyzer (well, any analyzer that is supported by any current C# compiler).

Indeed, one of the things that makes variables so powerful is that they can contain arbitrary values, passed around in your code, manipulated, etc. It is this same power that makes it impractical to try to detect at compile time what the value of a variable *would* be at run time.

It's not clear from your question what broader issue you're trying to resolve. But whatever it is, you're going about it in the wrong way. I recommend you post a new question that clearly and precisely explains what that broader issue is, so that you can receive some specific help on that.